# I am getting this error while running web project in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

```
ERROR - Ant is misconfigured and cannot be run.



java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openide.util.RequestProcessor.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.<clinit>(BridgeImpl.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.createAntInstance(AntBridge.java:321)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.getAntInstance(AntBridge.java:274)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.getInterface(AntBridge.java:263)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
        at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)
```

I tried to find out many ways but was not able to solve...Can any one give me suggession
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a [thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic10303.html&highlight=) on the Netbeans forums about this.  I looks like a compatibility isue between Netbeans and certain versions of Subversion.